# ZenDesk API Call From NetSuite Not Working

Tags: api, rest, netsuite, zendesk

I'm trying to send data from NetSuite to ZenDesk via the ZenDesk API.  Problem is, I can not get it to authenticate by placing the authentication inside the header.  Has anyone seen any articles on doing it this way?  I've tried adding it as {email}:{password} and {email}/token:{token} with no luck.

I have tested the password and the token using curl.  So I do know that the password is correct.  Any thoughts on this one?

I've also tried using Postman to create the authentication and it worked as well.  Oddly enough, though, I can not use that authentication in any other application.  I can paste is into the header (in Postman) with no issues, but when I try to do that via Advanced Rest Client (Chrome Extension) it won't work, nor will it work in the header from NetSuite.

I'm guessing there must be something that I am missing that Postman is doing by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally you have to provide credentials as a header e.g. a GET request like:

```
var url = 'https://...';
var cred = 'username' +':'+ 'password';
var headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : nlapiEncrypt(cred, 'base64');
};
nlapiRequestURL(url, null, headers);
```

Netsuite has a new method that apparently helps with this: `nlapiRequestURLWithCredentials` but I've not bothered figuring it out since the above is well tested and has worked with multiple remote systems.

Comment: Thanks @bknights.  Not sure why I never could get it to work by writing the headers as header['Authorization']='...'.  I tried your way and (after adding in 'Basic ' in front of the nlapiEncrypt it works.  Agreed with the comment about nlapiRequestWithCredential...  Especially with the new code coming out next year...  Thanks!